# WebView and Gallery in android

Tags: android

I have a `Gallery` and a few images stored in it.

On selecting the images i want some URL s to get opened on the top of this gallery(As a web view only).
For example If i click on a particular image i need a url to get opened.
I tried using `ViewSwitcher` and since I am a begginner i couldn move further.

Can someone tell if this is possible or suggest me the ways?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

You basically need to use `setOnItemClickListener` and there add the code to lunch an url with an `Intent`.